# How to access platfrom.sh data from Command line interface, setup process?

Tags: command-line-interface, platform.sh

I want to access all Platform.sh data from command line interface, any Platform.sh users can you pls help me how to setup the process. How to access project user access list using command line interface

How to use below script in cmd :

**p  user:list -p PROJECTID --- To list users**

How to connect platform.sh to cmd,

Answer (score 1):

I think by CMD you mean Windows CMD, correct?

For Windows you will use Scoop.

```bash
# Platform.sh Docs: https://docs.platform.sh/administration/cli.html

scoop bucket add platformsh https://github.com/platformsh/homebrew-tap.git
scoop install platform
```

Scoop **must be installed via Windows PowerShell** (see instructions [here](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install#prerequisites)), but **once installed it can be used from CMD**